# when changing a single todo into a textfield instead of all of todos

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to create a react component. If a user clicks on the edit button on a to-do item, it should replace the specific clicked todo area with a text field.

**What do I expect to see**

When a user clicks on one of the to-do items, that item becomes into a text field, which can then be edited.

**What do I actually see**

When a user clicks on one of the to-do items, all items become into text fields.

Here is my code:

PARENT

```
handleEditClick = (e,id,text) => {
    this.setState({val: !this.state.val})
  }


  render() {

    return (
     <div style={{display: "flex"}}>
       <div>
         {this.props.todos.map(todo => (
           <div key={todo.id}>
            <EditButton todo={todo} val={this.state.val} text={this.state.text} 
            handleEditClick={(e, id, text) => this.handleEditClick(e, id, text)}/>
          </div>
         ))}
     </div>
     </div>
    )
  }
}
```

CHILD(EDITBUTTON):

```
const EditButton = (props) => {
  if(!props.val) {
    return(
      <div>
       <List>
        <ListItem
          role={undefined}
          dense
          button
          onClick={() => this.updateTodo(props.todo)}
        ><Checkbox
            checked={props.todo.complete}
         />
          <ListItemText primary={props.todo.text} />
          <ListItemSecondaryAction>
          <Button mini color="secondary" variant="fab"
                  disabled={props.todo.complete}
                  onClick={(e) => props.handleEditClick(e, props.todo.id, props.todo.text)}
           >
          <Icon>edit_icon</Icon>
          </Button>
            <IconButton onClick={() => this.removeTodo(props.todo)}>
              <CloseIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </ListItemSecondaryAction>
        </ListItem>
       </List>
      </div>
    )
  }else {
    return(
      <TextField
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
          label=""
          margin="normal"
          fullWidth
          value={props.text}
          color="secondary"
      />
    )
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This example is not complete, but it does show how to implement what you descript. The program with your code was when you update the status of edit, it is updating every single item's status.

https://codesandbox.io/s/x7rvqm6xz4

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, TextField } from "@material-ui/core";

class Todos extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todos: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      todos: this.props.todos.map(todo => ({ name: todo, isEdit: false }))
    });
  }

  handleEdit(name) {
    const { todos } = this.state;
    const updateTodos = todos.map(todo => {
      if (todo.name === name) {
        return { name: todo.name, isEdit: !todo.isEdit };
      }
      return todo;
    });
    this.setState({ todos: updateTodos });
  }

  _renderTodos() {
    if (!this.state.todos) {
      return null;
    }
    return this.state.todos.map(todo => {
      return (
        <div key={todo.name}>
          {todo.isEdit ? <TextField /> : <span>{todo.name}</span>}
          <Button onClick={() => this.handleEdit(todo.name)}>Click</Button>
        </div>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.props.todos.length > 0) {
      return null;
    }
    return <div>{this._renderTodos()}</div>;
  }
}

export default Todos;
```

Basically, this component takes a list of todos. Put them into a state, and this state tracks whether to display them as todos or `TextField`.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before. See in [CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/v8r0yj4y8y).

There is `TodoList` class that can accept `todos` and `saveEditedTodo` as props. It has `editedTodo` state which dinamically change when "Edit" button is clicked. Of course, it contains `id` and `text`.

```
import React from "react";

export default class extends React.Component {
  state = {
    editedTodo: null
  };

  toggleEditTodo = (todo = null) => {
    this.setState({ editedTodo: todo });
  };

  onChangeTodoText = text => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      editedTodo: Object.assign(prevState.editedTodo, { text })
    }));
  };

  submitTodoForm = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.saveEditedTodo(this.state.editedTodo);
    this.setState({
      editedTodo: null
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { editedTodo } = this.state;
    const { todos } = this.props;
    return (
      <ul>
        {todos.map(todo => (
          <li key={todo.id}>
            {todo === editedTodo ? (
              // Show text field
            ) : (
              // Show todo
            )}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```